# An Interface Implementation error that I can't resolve

Tags: java, interface

I've been trying to implement service registration using rmi. It's demonstrating a light bulb controlled remotely between a client and a server.

This is my light bulb interface:

```
public interface RMILightBulb extends java.rmi.Remote{

      public void on() throws java.rmi.RemoteException{}
      public void off() throws java.rmi.RemoteException{}
      public boolean isOn() throws java.rmi.RemoteException{}
}
```

This is where I attempt to implement the RMILightBulb interface:

```
    public class RMILightBulbImpl extends java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject 
    implements RMILightBulb {

    public RMILightBulbImpl() throws java.rmi.RemoteException{

          setBulb(false);
    }

    private boolean lightOn;

    public void on() throws java.rmi.RemoteException{
         setBulb(true);
    }

    public void off() throws java.rmi.RemoteException{
         setBulb(false);
    }


    public boolean isOn() throws java.rmi.RemoteException{
         return getBulb();
    }

    public void setBulb(boolean value){
         lightOn = value;
    }

    public boolean getBulb(){
         return lightOn;
    }


 }
```

When trying to compile this, I get this error:

```
    error: RMILightBulbImpl is not abstract does not override abstract method isOn() in RMILightBulb
```

I have tried using the @Override annotation but still run into this problem. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you add the full `RMILightBulbImpl` code? Cause as it stands now, it's indeed abstract, let alone the fact that it doesn't compile

Comment: Added  RMILightBulbImpl code

Comment: well, as duffymo pointed out, your interface methods are not abstract, so I wonder how it did compile in the first place

Answer (score 2):

Wrong.  It should look like this:

```
public interface RMILightBulb extends java.rmi.Remote {

      void on() throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
      void off() throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
      boolean isOn() throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
}
```

Why bother with RMI?  CORBA is dead.  The world has moved on to web services, because simple and open win.

Comment: I removed the {} at the end of the method.  No implementation unless you're using JDK 8 and default.

Comment: Exploring RMI as part of my studies

Comment: Why waste time studying the wrong things? Don't bother with RMI or applets.

Comment: I'd love to move along but I'm afraid my professor is stuck in his ways.

Comment: That's the sign of a professor who stopped learning too long ago.  What a shame.